# Show that the map $\epsilon \to z_{\epsilon}$ is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a domain containing the unit disc $D=\{z| |z| \le 1 \}$. Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero at $z=0$ and vanishes nowhere in the unit disc.

Let $f_{\epsilon}(z)=f(z)+ \epsilon g(z)$. Show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small then

a) $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ has a unique zero in the unit disc.

b) Show that the map $\epsilon \to z_{\epsilon}$ is continuous

My try:

For (a): Since  $f$ has a simple zero at $z=0$ and vanishes nowhere in the unit disc, on $|z|=1$ ,$f$ attains the minimum value (say $\delta \gt 0$). Since $g$ is holomorphic on $D$, $g$ attains its maximum (say $M$). Then we have $$|f_{\epsilon}(z)-f(z)|=| \epsilon g(z)| \lt \epsilon M$$

For $\epsilon \lt \frac{\delta}{M}$, on $|z|=1$, we have $$|f_{\epsilon}(z)-f(z)| \lt \delta \le |f(z)|$$ . The conclusion follows by Rouche's theorem.

For (b) 
  I have no idea on how to proceed.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a holomorphic function $h$ has a zero of multiplicity $k$ at $z_0$, then we have $h(z) = (z-z_0)^k\cdot \tilde{h}(z)$ with $\tilde{h}$ holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and $\tilde{h}(z_0) \neq 0$. Thus we have

$$\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{k(z-z_0)^{k-1}\tilde{h}(z) + (z-z_0)^k\tilde{h}'(z)}{(z-z_0)^k\tilde{h}(z)} = \frac{k}{z-z_0} + \frac{\tilde{h}'(z)}{\tilde{h}(z)},$$

and the second summand is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. The residue of $\frac{h'}{h}$ in $z_0$ is therefore $k$. Then

$$z\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{k\cdot z}{z-z_0} + z\frac{\tilde{h}'(z)}{\tilde{h}(z)},$$

so

$$\operatorname{Res} \biggl(z\frac{h'}{h}; z_0\biggr) = \operatorname{Res} \biggl(\frac{k\cdot z}{z-z_0}; z_0\biggr) = k\cdot z_0.$$

Here, $f_\epsilon$ has only one zero in the unit disk (counting multiplicities), and therefore

$$z_\epsilon = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} z\cdot\frac{f_\epsilon'(z)}{f_\epsilon(z)}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} z\cdot\frac{f'(z) + \epsilon g'(z)}{f(z) + \epsilon g(z)}\,dz,$$

which shows that the function $\epsilon \mapsto z_\epsilon$ is continuous [even holomorphic], since the integrand depends continuously [holomorphically] on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to understand the very last sentence on why $z \mapsto z_{\epsilon}$ is holomorphic. Can we differentiate with respect to $\epsilon$ inside the integral? Is this part of something more general?

Comment: @user135520 Yes, one can differentiate under the integral. But it's more idiomatic to use the continuity (by the dominated convergence theorem) and then Morera's theorem (change the order of integration by Fubini) to see that an integral whose integrand depends holomorphically on a parameter depends holomorphically on that parameter [when that is the case, which most of the time - and particularly here - it is, but there are exceptions].

Comment: So if I name the integrand $H_{\epsilon}(z)= z \cdot \frac{f'_{\epsilon}(z)}{f_{\epsilon}(z)}$. Do we apply dominated convergence to something like $H_{\epsilon +\frac{1}{n}}$? I guess, I'm trying to see what sequence of functions to which we are applying the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: You need to consider arbitrary sequences converging to $\epsilon$, not only a particular sequence. In cases like this, where the domain of integration is compact and the integrand continuous (jointly, as a function of all involved variables, here $z$ and $\epsilon$), you can also show the continuity in a more elementary way. For each compact set $E$ such that $H_{\epsilon}(z)$ has no singularity on $E \times \{ z : \lvert z\rvert = 1\}$, $(\epsilon, z) \mapsto H_{\epsilon}(z)$ is uniformly continuous there, and then the standard estimate yields the continuity of the integral.

Comment: Given $\eta > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert H_{\epsilon_1}(z) - H_{\epsilon_2}(z)\rvert \leqslant \eta$ for all $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \in E$ with $\lvert \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2\rvert \leqslant \delta$ and all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, and hence $$\Biggl\lvert \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} H_{\epsilon_1}(z) - H_{\epsilon_2}(z)\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \eta\cdot 2\pi\,,$$ which gives you the uniform continuity of $$I(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} H_{\epsilon}(z)\,dz$$ on $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the elementary estimate, it's very helpful. Going back to what you said about Morera's theorem, my guess, is that we are hoping to show that $\int_{\gamma} H_{\alpha_{n}}(z)=0$ for any sequence $\alpha_{n} \to \epsilon$ and $C^{1}$ closed curve $\gamma$ in the disk. Do we get this by Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @user135520 Once we have the continuity, Morera's theorem asserts the analyticity of $I(\epsilon)$ once we've seen that $$\int_{\partial \Delta} I(\epsilon)\,d\epsilon = 0$$ for all triangles $\Delta$ contained in the domain of $I$. That follows by Cauchy's and Fubini's theorems since $$\int_{\partial \Delta} I(\epsilon)\,d\epsilon = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} H_{\epsilon}(z)\,dz\,d\epsilon = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \int_{\partial \Delta} H_{\epsilon}(z)\,d\epsilon\,dz\,,$$ where the change of order of integration is justified by

Comment: Fubini's theorem, and the inner integral $\int_{\partial \Delta} H_{\epsilon}(z)\,d\epsilon$ vanishes for every $z$ by Cauchy's theorem. [Of course one can construct situations where Fubini's theorem isn't applicable, but in most naturally arising situations there's no problem.]

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for taking the time to explain all this to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't the domain of $I$ a small interval of the form $[0,a)$? So how do we define a triangle for the domain of $I$ here?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician We can let $\epsilon$ be a _complex_ number of small modulus (small enough to guarantee that $f(z) + \epsilon g(z)$ has no zeros on the unit circle), so that the domain is a small disc with centre $0$. Even if one is only interested in real arguments, it can be useful to consider complex arguments because that often gives all the regularity one may want with less effort than would be needed for a purely real proof.